# Take the value from a lookuptable and calculate the total score for every record

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL and I have the following two tables:

Table `ApplicationAssessment` -  `RequestID` is the primary key:

| RequestID | NumUsers | RegulatoryImpact | ReputationalImpact | Total Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 7 | 7 | 8 |  |
| 2000 | 17 | 18 | 9 |  |
| 3000 | 19 | 7 | 7 |  |

Table `LookupTable` - `LookupID` is the primary key

| LookupID | LookupValue | LookupScore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | Chennai | 0 |
| 8 | Mumbai | 1 |
| 9 | Pune | 2 |
| 17 | 10 | 10 |
| 18 | 100+ | 10 |
| 19 | 1000+ | 20 |

The columns in the `ApplicationAssessment` table (`NumUsers, RegulatoryImpact, ReputationalImpact`) hold the values of the `lookupID`.

Every `lookupID` has the `LOOkupscore`. I want to calculate the total score for every `requestID`.

- For example for `requestID = 1000` it will be: 0 + 0 + 1 = **1**
- For `requestID = 2000`, it will be 10 + 10 + 2 = **22**

How do I do this programmatically? It's a sort of a `VLOOKUP` like in Excel. I am new to SQL, sorry for not trying out but asking the answer.

Comment: Unpivot NumUsers&RegulatoryImpact&ReputationalImpact, join on the lookuptable and aggregate `select *
from ApplicationAssessment as a
cross apply
(
  select sum(lt.LookupScore) as totscore
  from (values(a.NumUsers),(a.RegulatoryImpact),(a.ReputationalImpact)) as u(u)
  join LookupTable as lt on u.u = lt.LookupID  
) as ts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply add 3 correlated sub-queries:

```
select a.*, Total_Score = 
      isnull((select LookupScore from LookupTable t where t.LookupID = a.NumUsers), 0)
    + isnull((select LookupScore from LookupTable t where t.LookupID = a.RegulatoryImpact), 0)
    + isnull((select LookupScore from LookupTable t where t.LookupID = a.ReputationalImpact), 0)
from ApplicationAssessment a;
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using 3 `left join` to `ApplicationAssessment`

```
select RequestID, NumUsers, RegulatoryImpact, ReputationalImpact, 
  coalesce(l.LookupScore,0) + coalesce(l2.LookupScore,0) + coalesce(l3.LookupScore,0) as total
from ApplicationAssessment t
left join LookupTable l on t.NumUsers = l.LookupID
left join LookupTable l2 on t.RegulatoryImpact = l2.LookupID
left join LookupTable l3 on t.ReputationalImpact = l3.LookupID
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ivovqGxu)